# How to define a type for object that store a dynamic mongodb query

Tags: typescript, mongodb

I need to assign a variable as a mongo query object in Typescript so that I can manipulate and build a mongo query dynamically from it.

For example, based on different input type - "select", "date_time".
The function generate a mongo query by different predefined query templates that is stored in a switch case and add those dynamic value in the expected position.

Eventually for different kinds of input I may get query like this

```
//date_time : 
{$and:[{{'date':{$gte:new Date(dateA),$lte:new Date(dateB)}}}]};
        
//select 
{$and:[{'lunch':{$eq:'optionA'}}];
```

The problem Im currently has is Typescript is very strict on type so I can't just use push method to push any object I desire, I have to, predefined all possible template to make it works. To my understanding that will generate immense amount of type just to generate this one query.

I can make the object any but then It kind of defeat the whole purpose of using typescript.

Any way to make it works without cheating with the any type?